How to determine the range of another parallel side $P_2$ of a trapezium when $P_1$, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are given?
I am interested in  finding the range of another parallel side of a trapezium with $P_1$ (a parallel side), $L_1$ (a leg) and $L_2$ (another leg) are given.
My attempt is as follows:
Draw a circle of radius $L_1$ at the origin and another circle of radius $L_2$ at $(P_1,0)$. Let $P_2$ be the parallel side in question.
So $P_2$ is a distance from $(L_1\cos \theta_1, L_1\sin \theta_1)$ to  $(P_1+L_2\cos \theta_2, L_2\sin \theta_2)$.
The relationship becomes:
\begin{cases}
P_2 = P_1+L_2\cos \theta_2 - L_1\cos \theta_1\\
L_1\sin \theta_1 = L_2\sin \theta_2
\end{cases}
My question is how to find the maximum and minimum of $P_2$. Note: Crossed trapeziums are not allowed.

Geometrically speaking, which points would you choose on the circles in order to maximize or minimize $P_2$?

The maximum is the sum of the three. The minimum is P1 - L1-L2 but not less the 0.
